# Apex Trigger is not inserting values in object

Tags: salesforce

I want to copy all the record of position object to position archive object whenever a position is deleted but it is not inserting anything in position archive object. Here is my code-

```
trigger ArchivePosition on Position__c (after delete)
{
    List<Position_Archive__c> arch = new List<Position_Archive__c>();
    List<Position__c> pos = new List<Position__c>();

    for(Position__c temp:trigger.old)
    {
        Position_Archive__c obj = new Position_Archive__c();
        obj.Name=temp.Name;
        arch.add(obj);
        System.debug(obj.Name);
    }
    try
    {
        insert arch;
        System.debug(arch);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Exception '+e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No exception. The values from trigger.old are getting stored in arch list but not reflecting in position archive object.